Leaking / Missing sillcock valve handle?
My building’s maintenance has disabled use of the outdoor garden hose hookup and I am trying to work around this.
Does anyone know what type of connection this is and how to fix it? I’m able to turn on the water with my 5/16” sillcock key but water leaks out of the valve control area. Seems like it is missing a bonnet?
I bought a 630-7755 repair kit on Amazon but it is too large to screw in.
Please let me know. I can provide additional photos if needed. Thanks!


Unless trying to put out a fire, work arounds might be deem if not illegal then against lease conditions.

post you picture again

connect your hose to the washing machine or dishwasher water supply.
